# Are these SMS-abbreviations reliable?

Tags: word-usage, slang, abbreviation

I found this shared on a Facebook group. 
I just want to to make sure this wasn't hoaxed before sharing in my own timeline.

- 8ung: Achtung
- AWS: Auf Wiedersehen
- div: danke im voraus
- GN8: Gute Nacht
- TABU: Tausend Bussis
- DAD: denke an dich
- WWW: wir werden warten
- JON: jetzt oder nie
- MAD: mag dich
- SMS: schreib mir schnell
- mamima: Mail mir mal
- MfG: Mit freundlichen Grüßen
- mumidire: Muss mit dir reden
- nfd: Nur für dich
- pin: Professioneller Internet Nutzer
- rumian: Ruf‘ mich an
- sfh: Schluss fur heute
- siw: Soweit ich weiß
- VV: Viel Vergnügen
- wigeesdi: Wie geht es dir?
- wztwd: Wo zum Teufel warst du?
- LG: Liebe Grüße
- HGW: Herzlichen Glückwunsch
- BB: Bis Bald
- g&k: Gruß & Kuss
- hegl: Herzlichen Glückwunsch
- ild: ich liebe dich

Comment: We can’t produce reliable sources for their actual usage, but I think most of them are phony and were never used (except in this hoax list). *LG/MfG* however are still very common these days. Maybe some people would also use and get *8ung/gn8*.

Comment: Neither the waste of screen estate nor unsearchable graphics wil win upvotes

Comment: Are *any* SMS abbreviations reliable?

Comment: Too broad. One abbreviation might be in common use, while others aren't.

Comment: Without reference, I'd understand maybe a fifth of that list.

Answer (score 1):

In SMS, each abbreviation that is not mentioned in the Duden should be agreed upon by the communicating people. Otherwise there is too much potential for misunderstanding each other.

So *mfg* is ok but sounds too formal for typical short messages, so I don't use it.
LG is fine.
N8 and 8ung are also fine since they won't be misunderstood.
All the others are risky.

Answer (score 1):

> LG, MfG, GN8

Apart from these three, I've never seen any of the others in actual use (with MfG not even being a real 'SMS/chat abbreviation', but rather a shortened version of something you would find in formal letters).

But even *if* any of these abbreviations are or were used at all, they are part of German teenage / net slang, so using them in everyday conversation comes with several risks:

- They may only be used and understood within a fairly limited group of speakers.
- They may be long outdated.
- They will seem awkward coming from a person beyond a certain age.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience as a native speaker in my thirties, only *LG*, *Liebe Grüße* is a widely used expression.